# Cannot Boot from DVD with ISO 14.04 (32-Bit)

Tags: boot

Have downloaded **now 3 times** Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and burned on DVD on my WIN 7 system.

After inserting the DVD in my XP3 computer (BIOS boot sequence is DVD and there after HDD), and restart, I do not get an Ubuntu but normal Windows.

**Is the burnt DVD at all bootable?**

The download-file(993 MB)and DVD shows this content on all 3 tries:ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso
and NOT the figure shown in the chapter "The DVD was not burned properly" marked Correct?

What is going wrong?

P.S.Had not burned the image, rather copied ISO
Used Image Burner and all went fine.
Thanks to all!

Comment: tyr to burn the .iso file as image, so that it would be bootable.

Comment: if you just want to install so download 14.04 .iso after that in your windows copy that .iso on a flash drive after that make your flash boot able by the here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly you only see the ubuntu.iso file on the DVD.

It seems as if you are burning the file *.iso on the disk but with a normal file system.

The ISO File itself has a file system inside. When opening with a DVD burning program the ISO-File it should burn the bootable DVD correctly.

You could try CDBurnerXP 4.5.3 for example to get a bootable DVD. It runs from XP up to Windows 8.1.

Regards
Makku